# FFMPEG mosaic/side-by-side-compositing from simultaneous DirectShow input devices

Tags: video, ffmpeg, webcam

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
ffmpeg.exe -y \
-f dshow -i video="Microsoft LifeCam Cinema" \
-f dshow -i video="Microsoft LifeCam VX-2000" \
-filter_complex "[0:v]pad=iw*2:ih:0[left];[left][1:v]overlay=W/2.0[fileout]" \
-map "[fileout]" -vcodec libx264 -f flv out.flv
```

Basically, I have 2 webcams and I would like to combine them into a single video file in which the frames are 2x1 in size with the frame from one camera in the left and the other on the right.

In other words, what might be termed "mosaic-ing" or "side-by-side compositing". This is *not* concatenation - i.e. one file after the other (so not using the concat filter).

I've gleamed that this use of `-filter_complex` to pad and then position the frames appears the prescribed way. Indeed, when I test this with files like so:

```
ffmpeg.exe -y -i test1.flv -i test2.flv -filter_complex "[0:v]pad=iw*2:ih:0[left];[left][1:v]overlay=W/2.0[fileout]" -map "[fileout]" -vcodec libx264 -f flv testout.flv
```

It works fine!

With the "live" version however, both cameras seem to start (their lights come on) but the capture stalls.

(Suspiciously like there is some DirectShow deadlock on the separate input device threads...)

**And so, I wonder is there some way to overcome this and force the two input stream's data to merge?**

I have also tried the extended format of the dshow filter option like so as well:

```
-f dshow -i video="Microsoft LifeCam Cinema":video="Microsoft LifeCam VX-2000"
```

But only one camera is then selected (I suspect this option is really only to enable separate video and audio streams to be combined).

I've also tried explicitly setting each input device to have the exact same frame size and rate with `-f dshow -video_size 640x480 -framerate 30`. No joy though. It still stalls once the camera is listed.

Here is the tail end of the output (with `-v debug` on):

```
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option y (overwrite output files) with argument 1.
Applying option v (set libav* logging level) with argument debug.
Applying option filter_complex (create a complex filtergraph) with argument [0:v]pad=iw*2:ih:0[left];[left][1:v]overlay=W/2.0[fileout].
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input file video=Microsoft LifeCam Cinema.
Applying option f (force format) with argument dshow.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: video=Microsoft LifeCam Cinema.
[dshow @ 00000000016e79a0] All info found
[dshow @ 00000000016e79a0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, dshow, from 'video=Microsoft LifeCam Cinema':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1130406.072000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0, 1, 1/10000000: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 640x480, 333333/10000000, 30 tbr, 10000k tbn, 30 tbc
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: input file video=Microsoft LifeCam VX-2000.
Applying option f (force format) with argument dshow.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: video=Microsoft LifeCam VX-2000.
[dshow @ 00000000016e79a0] real-time buffer 101% full! frame dropped!
```

**EDIT** Further details trying to fix within the code...*

I've always understood from past Windows DirectShow work that multiple calls to CoInitialize() on the same thread is bad. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Perhaps I've misunderstood how FFMPEG is multi-threaded (i.e. if each input device is on it's own thread) but I thought to just try regulating the call with a guard variable (a `static int com_init = 0;` - this should probably be mutex-ed...).

e.g. in libavdevice/dshow.c method `dshow_read_header`

```
889    if (com_init==0)
890     CoInitialize(0);
891    com_init++
```

And similar for dshow_read_close

```
170    com_init--;
171    if (com_init==0)
172     CoUninitialize()
```

Sadly, this **doesn't work**. The first camera starts but the second doesn't and the error is:

```
[dshow @ 0000000000301760] Could not set video options
video=Microsoft LifeCam VX-2000: Input/output error
```

(Worth a shot. Looks like each input device is indeed on the same thread...)

Comment: Perhaps this question is better suited for SuperUser after all (but then, I am hacking the ffmpeg code as well...)?

Comment: Multiple `CoInitialize` are OK, as long as they are paired with uninitialization respectively. From the log it seems that FFmpeg's DriectShow hosting code does not work properly with the camera. Another possible cause is that they are both USB and they just cannot work together due to insufficient USB bandwidth.

Comment: The reason might be that you didn't set PTS in the filter chain, which will cause a syncing issue, since both cameras will produce their own PTS for their videos. You might try reading [this FFmpeg tutorial](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/Create%20a%20mosaic%20out%20of%20several%20input%20videos) to see if it helps in any way. I believe you could just replace file inputs with live inputs to get what you need.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's comments. Having returned to this the other day - I actually tried 2 different cameras (a Microsoft LifeCam and an Trust WB-3320X) and lo! It worked. The problem was only aparent when using the two Microsoft cameras as per above.  With these 2 cameras I did try explicitly setting the PTS as part of the filter_complex - but no joy. It still looks like a low-level Dshow issue. Perhaps the same Dshow input filter clashes in some way?